# Pandas Dataframe row iteration and insert blank row

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, xlsxwriter

I'm new in python. I have a data frame and I'm writing it into excel. What I want to insert a blank row with substring "Total" where the column "Placement ID" values change and get the sum of fields values of other columns.

The data currently looks like this way.

http://prntscr.com/i0ndav

Looking to convert this in that way.

http://prntscr.com/i0nful

Data is here

https://drive.google.com/open?id=15gef0zEReQb7qA7TsJSxIhYxLVVJLK4X

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do with NaN? Drop them? Fill them with 0? Also some of your columns have strings in them instead of ints/floats (e.g. nan% vs NaN).

Comment: @IanThompson, Yes I wanted to drop them. I'll work on converting them to it. Would you please help with  inserting blank row and adding the numbers of each iteration

Comment: @IanThompson This doesn't look like working in my way. Its not writing the index values in excel. Also I just don't want to get sum of column S to AA. Only wanted to get sum of column E to R. substring "Total" can be anywhere in between on placement Id to day. Also i want all columns to write in excel.

Comment: Please see my newest edits

Comment: What have you tried? Please dont link to outside sources. Stackover people wont click on links.

Answer (score 1):

How's this look?

```
# import pandas
import pandas as pd

# import data
df = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\IT045886\Downloads\Data.xlsx", skiprows = 12)

# convert str(floats) to actual floats
for col in df.loc[:, 'KM_Impressions':].columns:
    df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col].copy(), errors = 'coerce')

# limit column selection
df1 = df.loc[:, :'Deep Engagements'].copy()

# drop NaN and pivot
subs = df1.dropna().pivot_table(index = [
    'Placement ID',
    'Placement#',
    'Metric',
    'Day'
], aggfunc = 'sum')

# sum on first three levels
subs_t = subs.sum(level = [0,1,2])

# insert 'Total' in 'Day' column
subs_t.insert(0, 'Day', 'Total')

# set 'Day' in index
subs_t.set_index('Day', append = True, inplace = True)

# concat sums and totals
df2 = pd.concat([subs, subs_t]).sort_index().reset_index()

# merge original columns back in, reorder columns
final = df2.merge(df, how = 'outer')[df.columns]

final
```

[image: output]

Documentation for `pd.to_numeric()` --> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html

```
errors = 'coerce' # invalid parsing will be set as NaN
```

Comment: That's cool, thank you so much, Would you please let me know what 'coerce' doing here.

Comment: Please see my edits

Comment: It worked Ian, Appreciate for your help.

Comment: Great! Please consider selecting it as the correct answer.